# Gulp Pipeline with global variable

Tags: gulp, pipe, tap

In a gulp task I need replace same links in a file.
In my task, I need:

- read all file in one directory (i.e. all *.css files)
- check if file names contains same words (i.e. min)
- generate an array with old-new string pairs
- replace all old string with new string

For this purpose I use gulp-batch-replace package with others.
My idea is create an array in first pipe ( array is a global array  variable), then pass it to next pipe where replace pairs. 
Gloabal array is created by tap call in pipe, but replace doesn't work. I think that this array is empty when i call pipe 2. 
The external call in tap is async ? Thanks

This is my code.

```
var tap = require('gulp-tap');
var replaceAll = require('gulp-batch-replace');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('pages', function () {

  var replaceThis = [];
  function replaceFileContent(file) {
    var newFileName = path.basename(file.path).trim();
    var oldFileName = newFileName.includes('.min') ?
      newFileName.replace('.min', '').trim() :
      newFileName.substr(0, newFileName.indexOf('.')) + '.min' + newFileName.substr(newFileName.indexOf('.')).trim();
      replaceThis.push([oldFileName, newFileName]);
      console.log(oldFileName + " ---> " + newFileName);
  }

  gulp.src('site/dist/css/**/*.css')
  .pipe(tap(replaceFileContent))
  .pipe(replaceAll(replaceThis))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/dist/'));

  console.log("end");

});
```